# Store values that are created in a loop outside of the loop in rust

Tags: loops, rust, tree, borrow-checker, ownership

I am working on a little parser that takes an S-Expression and transforms it into a tree data structure. Since trees are not so easy in Rust to do bidirectional I want to make it only one-directional (each node only knows it's children, not it's parents). To still be able to access nodes that have been created in the past, I want to store all nodes in a Vector and keep an index that tells me which node is where. E.g. a node would have a field `parent_index`, with the index of it's parent node in the vector, without needing to have a direct reference to it.

So, while I iterate over the String that is my s-expression, I am creating new nodes and want to push them into the vector, as well as assigning child relationships.

for clarifications an S-Expression can be this `(w1 (w2 t1) (w3 t2))` or something like this `(S (F (FIRSTWORD This) (SECONDWORD is)) (Z (THIRDWORD a) (FOURTHWORD sentence)))`, or just a terminal like `Hello`

A lot is still missing but my idea looks like this. My question now is: How can I create all these Trees inside the loop and store them into the vector outside of the loop?
It seems that the borrow checker has some probelems with this...
I am very grateful for any help! Thank you :)

My idea looks like this:

```
pub struct Tree{
    pub root: String,
    pub children: Vec<Tree>
}



fn parse_to_tree(mut s_expr: String) -> Tree{
    
    // Vector for all nodes
    let mut all_nodes:Vec<&Tree> = Vec::new(); 
    // Index of node we are working on
    let mut curr_node_index = 0;

    while !s_expr.is_empty(){


        // get first char from s expression
        let mut c_c = s_expr.remove(0);
        
        //Names: c_c: current_char, c_w: current:word
        // only continue if we start with '(', otherwise Leaf
        while c_c == '('{

            let mut c_w = String::from("");            
            
            while c_c != ' '{
                c_c = s_expr.remove(0);
                c_w.push(c_c);                
            }
            println!("{}", c_w);
            let node = Tree{root: c_w, children: Vec::new()};
            //Here I want to push the node by reference to the all_nodes_vector
            all_nodes.push(&node); // HERE occurs the error: borrowed value does not live      long enough...
            if !all_nodes.is_empty(){
                
                // Here I want to to push the new node as a child to the old current_node
                all_nodes[curr_node_index].children.push(node);
                

            }
            curr_node_index += 1;


            
        }
        return Tree{root: s_expr, children: Vec::new()};
        
    }

    return Tree{root: s_expr, children: Vec::new()};
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that (safely): someone, somewhere, while building this tree, will have to hold both a node and the list of nodes that contains this node. And (at least) the reference to the node will be mutable (because we need to build it), causing a violation of the borrow rules.

The solution is simple: just give up on using references. Store all nodes in a vector, and only keep indices to this vector. This is easy, effective and idiomatic.